# How do I check if a process is alive in Python on Linux?

Tags: python, process

I have a process id in Python. I know I can kill it with os.kill(), but how do I check if it is alive ? Is there a built-in function or do I have to go to the shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `subprocess` module to spawn process.
There is **proc.poll()** function - it returns `None` if process is still alive, otherwise it returns process returncode.

**http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html**

Answer (score 14):

`os.kill` does not kill processes, it sends them signals (it's poorly named).

If you send signal 0, you can determine whether you are allowed to send other signals.  An error code will indicate whether it's a permission problem or a missing process.

See `man 2 kill` for more info.

Also, if the process is your child, you can get a `SIGCHLD` when it dies, and you can use one of the `wait` calls to deal with it.

Comment: It is not poorly named. It is named to reflect the Unix command kill which also send signals, and is thus a generalization of sending a kill signal.

Answer (score 0):

With psutil you can check if a process id exists:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.pid_exists(1234))
```