# Dymola crash / python should initiate restart of program and script

Tags: python, crash, restart, dymola

First off, as I'm not asking to debug specific code (the code is working) and as the code is quite entangled, I'm not going to provide it. Rather, I'm asking this question hoping someone has a good idea on how to implement a solution for the following problem in python.

For a series of simulations I use the program "Dymola". My python script creates a random set of 100 inputs, runs Dymola and passes them to Dymola which in turn performs a simulation based on each input. This happens in a loop from range 0 to 100 leading to 10 000 simulation results.

After each loop (-> after having generated 100 outputs by Dymola), I save the data set in a numpy array, calling it "out1.npy" (and "in1.npy"). If everything went accordingly, out1 would be overwritten after each loop and at the end I'd have an out1.npy file consisting of 10 000 results.

However, Dymola crashes often (Windows error: "Dymola has stopped working") after having processed some inputs and right now I don't have a clue why this is happening.

What I do up till now is pressing "Close the program" in the Windows error dialogue, checking up to which loop the simulation has run in the console (e.g. time: 50) and rerun the loop from range(50,100) and manually increasing the name of the output-file to "out2.npy" so that "out1.npy" is not overwritten (otherwise I'd lose the data of the first 50). At the end, I create the complete dataset by stacking all the out1,out2,out3,... files via the function np.stack.

What I'd like my python script to do is to close the program after it has crashed (so that the windows error dialogue disappears), to readout the time of the last loop processed from the console, adapting the range by this value (e.g. 50) and rerun the python script. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using the python interface to control dymola? If so, you could maybe use `dymola._dymola_process.poll()` to check if dymola is still alive (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114332/8725275 for poll()) and disable the debug dialog for Dymola as described on [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/configuring-automatic-debugging#excluding-an-application-from-automatic-debugging

Comment: I think you should contact your support-channel, since Dymola isn't supposed to crash. (Especially not for different input signals to a model.)

Comment: Two ideas: First, wrap the call in a try-catch statement, and for failures, print out the input values. Try these in a normal simulation from the GUI. Second idea: You can also enable the GUI from python, it is disabled by default. If you enable it, you might be able to see some intermediate messages.

Comment: @marco Yes, I'm using the python interface to control dymola. Thanks for the command, I will try to implement it.

Comment: @Hans Olsson will do that.

Comment: @matth Can you tell me how to enable the GUI from python?

Comment: @DorianIL Search the Dymola User Manual part 2 for `nowindow`, or have a look at the Python wrapper documentation, it is available on your computer at `file:///C:/Program%20Files/Dymola%202019%20FD01/Modelica/Library/python_interface/doc/index.html`

Comment: @matth The whole script is in try now, except is checking with the command dymola._dymola_process.poll() if dymola is not None (if it's not None, dymola has crashed). Is there any way to implement a rerun of the loop in try in the exception? in the sense of: If there is an exception, try to run the loop again?

Comment: You can put your code into function, and call it from both branches of the try except maybe!?

Comment: And another comment: If you really just change parameters between simulations, you should consider using FMI instead! From Dymola, compile to FMI, then simulate using PyFMI or FMPy.